# Error Index 999 out of bounds for length 999

Tags: java, array, bucle-for

Me piden el siguiente enunciado. Ya tengo este código pero me marca un error que no entiendo, si alguien me puede instruir, le agradezco

> Se desea realizar un programa que genere, aleatoriamente una lista de
> 999 de números reales en el rango de 0 a 2000 y los ordene de forma
> creciente utilizando el método de intercambio

Código

```
import java.util.Random;

public class ListaAleatoria {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int numeroAle[] = new int[999], aux;
        Random R = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < numeroAle.length; i++) {
            numeroAle[i] = R.nextInt(2000) + 0;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < (numeroAle.length - 1); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < (numeroAle.length); j++) {
                if (numeroAle[j] > numeroAle[j + 1]) {
                    aux = numeroAle[j];
                    numeroAle[j] = numeroAle[j + 1];
                    numeroAle[j + 1] = aux;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < numeroAle.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("No" + (i + 1) + ": " + numeroAle[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:
> Index 999 out of bounds for length 999 at
> listaaleatoria.ListaAleatoria.main(ListaAleatoria.java:13)

Answer (score 3):

si declaras un array como

```
int [] array =new int[5];
```

significa que la longitud de ese array es 5
y sus indices seran 0,1,2,3,4

si yo inicio un for y coloco lo siguiente cuando llegue al ultimo indice sera 4+1 existe ese indice??? no verdad

```
for(int i=0;i<array .lenght;i++){
  System.out.println(i+1);
}
```

es lo que estas haciendo al colocar (j+1)estas desbordando la longitud de tu array ,el segundo for debe ser asi el indice i+1 por que este es menor a la longitud de tu array -1

```
 for (int i = 0; i < (numeroAle.length - 1); i++) { 
        for (int j = 0; j < (numeroAle.length); j++) { 

            if (numeroAle[j] > numeroAle[i + 1]) {
                aux = numeroAle[j];

                numeroAle[j] = numeroAle[i + 1]; 
                numeroAle[i + 1] = aux;
            }
        }
    }
```